# VS Code not hitting breakpoints for Node app running in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, babeljs, nodemon, vscode-debugger

## Summary

I'm running a node app inside a docker container can't get the VS code debugger to hit breakpoints.

### Docker Setup

The docker container exposes port 5859. Inside the container the node app is ran with this command:

`nodemon -L --watch src --exec babel-node src/server.js -- --inspect=0.0.0.0:5859 --nolazy`

It reports that the debugger is listening:

```
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /app/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/server.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:5859 --nolazy`
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:5859/5939f6b6-5ade-4ce5-9694-7df5f5b8385b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

### VS Code Setup

And when I fire up the debug profile in VS Code it appears to attach. Below is line from the logs of the running docker container.
[image]
However, no breakpoints are hit when I set them. Is this a babel-node issue? Is there any suggested path forward to get node debugging to work with `babel-node`?

[image]

My VS Code debug config:

```
  {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Docker: GraphQL",
        "port": 5859,
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "restart": true,
        "remoteRoot": "/app",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to get this to work with nodemon, but modifying my `.babelrc` file to include inline source maps triggered VS code to hit the breakpoints I set. My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "presets": [
                ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
                "stage-1"
            ]
        },
        "development": {
            "presets": [
                ["es2015"],
                "stage-1"
            ], 
            "sourceMaps": "inline",
            "retainLines": true
        }    }
}
```

And the corresponding script that docker calls in `package.json`. Port 5859 is exposed in the docker-compose file.

```
"start:docker": "babel-node src/server.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:5859 --nolazy",
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else arriving via a search like me. In my case changing `${workspaceRoot}` to `${workspaceFolder}` in my vs code `launch.json` file worked to get a previously working project debuggable again.